# in Torch, why is NIN and VGG19 network 1-top predicting always 670?

Tags: deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network, prediction, torch

I'm working with Torch7 on Ubuntu, I'm trying to apply a deep neural Network that trained on ImageNet2012 such as NIN or VGG19 to a single image.

This is my code.

```
require('image')
require('nn')
require('pretty-nn')


net = torch.load('NIN_Test/NIN_Imagenet_W_model.t7')
--net = torch.load('NIN_Test/VGG_19_W_model.t7')
net:evaluate()

images = image.load('NIN_Test/5ee446f7fdedd01db6c7ea3d43df72b46807911b.thumb.jpeg')


mean= torch.Tensor({0.485, 0.456, 0.406})
std =torch.Tensor({0.229, 0.224, 0.225})

images3 = image.scale(images, 224, 224,'bilinear')

for i=1,3 do 
    images3[i] = images3[i]:add(-mean[i]):div(std[i]) 
end

image.display{image = images3}

output = net:forward(images3):view(-1)

classes indices = torch.sort(output, true)
```

when I test different images for example image of human, cat, dog, bird and etc the 1-top predict is 670th class or label, means

```
t7> return  indices[1]
670
```

what should I do?
what's the problem?

Comment: where do you change images in your code?

Comment: in line image.load(). I change address for new image

Comment: what happens when you print the `output` tensor? do you get the same values each time?

Comment: each time high probabitity is for 670th output.

Comment: could you maybe add the result of `print(net)` and `print(output)` to your question? and what is exactly `classes indices`?

Comment: I sort the output of the Net, and classes contain probabilities and indices contain index of output after sort.

Comment: haven't you forgotten a comma between `classes` and `indices`?

Comment: no effect in output